# Prove that $\triangle SBP$ is an isoceles triangle.

Tags: geometry

> Given $\angle ABx < 90^\circ$ and points $P$ and $Q$, $M$ and $N$ lying respectively on $AB$ and $Bx$ such that $\dfrac{AP}{AB} = \dfrac{PQ}{PB}$ and $\angle AMP = \angle PNQ$ $(AP > PQ$ and $AB > PB)$. Let $(AMP) \cap (PNQ) = S$ $(P \ne S)$. Prove that $\triangle SBP$ is an isoceles triangle.

[image]

I think that I need to prove that $Q, A, M, N$ are concyclic(, perhaps even $QAMN$ is a harmonic quadrilateral,) and $\triangle AMP \sim \triangle PNQ$.

We have that $\angle AMP = \angle ANP$ and $\angle PNQ = \angle PSQ \implies SP$ is the bisector of $\angle QSA$

$\implies \dfrac{AP}{AS} = \dfrac{PQ}{SQ} \implies \dfrac{AB}{AS} = \dfrac{QB}{QS}$. But I can't see anything further down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the centre of $(AMP)$ be $O$ and the centre of $(PNQ)$ be $T$.

And, $\triangle APO \sim \triangle PQT$, therefore, $O, T, B$ is colinear (because of $\dfrac{AP}{AB} = \dfrac{PQ}{PB}$).

Also, line $OT$ is perpendicular at the midpoint of $SP$.

Therefore, $SB = PB$.

Comment: How could you be certain that $OT$ is the perpendicular bisector of $SP$? I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: It is because △SOT≡△POT.  Let V be an intersection point of OT and SP. Now, △SOV≡△TOV.  Hence, ∠SVO=90 and SV=PV.

Comment: Thanks for that. You could add that to your answer for clarification (if you wish to).